# OpenCV 3.0 with Qt 5.5: Toolbar icons and control panel not shown

Tags: qt, opencv, opencv3.0, highgui, qt5.5

I built OpenCV 3.0.0 with Qt support (Qt 5.5) in order to try some of the advanced HighGUI features:

```
cv::namedWindow("Main", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL | CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO | CV_GUI_EXPANDED);
cv::createButton("test", buttonCb);
while (1)
    cv::waitKey(1);
```

I expected to see a window called "Main" with a nice toolbar as well as a control panel containing a push button "test" (see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html)).

What I do get is a window called "Main" with a toolbar where the icons are missing (see screenshot) and the control panel does not appear at all.

[image: screenshot]

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including GTK or VTK libraries in your CMake file?

```
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
```

or

```
find_package(GTK REQUIRED)
include(${GTK_USE_FILE})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I cannot find any indication on the internet that OpenCV or Qt has VTK or GTK as a dependency. Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: Not really, the advice is based on personal experience. Give it a try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you build opencv as STATIC lib , try to build it as DLLs, not only icons appears but also the style of the GUI is much prettier. If you are not absolutely obliged to use opencv as static lib, this may be a solution. 
The control panel is not shown by default, you can display it by right-clicking on your main window and choose the last entry of the menu, or just use the shortcut CTRL+P.

Answer (score 0):

I just met this issue and fixed. Even the issue is old I wanted to answer.

Firstly this issue is related to the QT. Because OpenCV imshow features supported by Qt. So OpenCV is needed to be installed with the cmake flag `-D WITH_QT=ON` Even I continued in this way, cmake is not able to find Qt:

```
--   GUI:                           GTK3
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.33)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.72.4)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
```

Qt installation is also needed for this issue. Even I installed Qt, this issue still continues. The reason is that OpenCV is not able to find Qt location. Generally Qt is installed to Qt but in my case it was in another location. I just specified the `Qt6_DIR` as `-D Qt6_DIR=/home/cvlab/Qt/6.4.3/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6` (if you are using Qt5 then you need to specify `Qt5_DIR` accordingly):

```
--   GUI:                           QT6
--     QT:                          YES (ver 6.4.3 )
--       QT OpenGL support:         YES (Qt6::OpenGL )
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.33)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.72.4)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so)
--     VTK support:                 NO
```

So now it is able to find Qt. I just re-installed OpenCV and get the GUI features.

Also the video includes answer is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSKirT38Foc)